# How to create a text file in shift JIS encoding using PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create a text file in shift JIS encoding(instead of ASCII) using PL/SQL's UTL_FILE.FOPEN???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can.

To be able to do that, you would need to change the `NLS_CHARARACTERSET` parameter for your database to `JA16SJISTILDE` (I guess, that is the CHARSET for Shift JIS, please confirm that).

If this is needed only for writing a file, then you should change the characterset, just for the session in which you are writing the file, and revert back to the default characterset of your environment. You can do that using `ALTER SESSION ...` command from your program.